# Can I submit iOS 9 beta build to iTunes Connect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios9, xcode7

I am new to Xcode and iOS coding. I updated my app to iOS 9, and I would like to submit it to the app store. Is this possible? Or will they not accept an iOS 9 build?

It works fine on both iOS 9 and iOS 8 devices.

Comment: Apple has never accepted app store submissions using beta tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PetahChristian is right. Apple does not allow you to submit beta build with beta version of Xcode, which is indeed suboptimal thing, as you won't be able to test your app until final version of Xcode comes out (this is all just in case you switched to Swift 2.0, otherwise just use Xcode 6.4 to submit the build).

Let's just hope that our users will be willing to accept possibly buggy apps when iOS 9 kicks in, as developers simply can't test them properly :).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So basically, at this point I can't update my app until iOS 9 is officially released / Xcode 7 is officially released? I have made changes within the app, but they are clearly not compatible with xcode 6.4 anymore because of the swift to swift 2 changes. So how would I approach this?

Comment: Well obviously i would say that you can't approach it in any other way but to wait for the final version of Xcode 7 :(... If you used Swift 2 in your project there's simply nothing you can do about it right now. Hopefully that will happen till mid September, end of September in worst case which makes it around 20 days of playing the waiting game, so yeah... it really sucks but it is how it is :(

Comment: What do you mean that iOS 9 apps can't be tested properly? Of course they can. You can give them to testers with iOS 9 beta.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info @BojanKopanja. And @ rmaddy in iTunes Connect, it is not allowing iOS 9 beta builds to be tested externally, with other users.

Comment: I haven't done it but there's a note at the top of iTunes Connect stating that you can submit iOS 9 builds to Test Flight and invite users to test. Otherwise there is the old tried and true method of using Adhoc deployment.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if third party systems like TestFairy would allow app distribution but i think that it should work normally as it's also a simple AdHoc deployment

Comment: I might be wrong, but with Xcode 9 beta, I have uploaded a number of versions to iTunes Connect, and didn't realize I was using a beta until it succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't submit an app using a beta version of Xcode.

As long as you did not update your project to Swift 2.0, you should be able to submit it using the released version of Xcode.

If you upgraded your project and it won't compile with Swift 1.2, you'll have to wait until Xcode 7 is released.

**Update:**

The beta has several purposes:

1. To test Apple's code and [report bugs to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com/).
2. To gain early access to new features and functionality of the SDK.  You beta test your new or upgraded app on iOS 9 and fix bugs.  When Xcode is released, you test against the release, then submit it.
3. To test existing apps to make sure they still work properly on (a prerelease of) iOS 9.  **You fix any bugs that may have turned up, but keep your code compatible with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.**  You submit using Xcode 6, and are able to submit any bug fixes in advance of Xcode 7 being released.

Ideally, you get to do all three things, but updating your app generally involves maintaining and working on different branches of your project.

This allows you to both support and fix issues for your released version, and add new features to an upcoming version.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer. I wish I had known this before I completely transformed the code into being iOS 9 compatible, and then changing a lot of the code.

Comment: Good opportunity to get up to speed with Source Control for this project, to let you checkout an earlier commit in the future :)  Time Machine backups are another option to recover your earlier code, but not as flexible as git!